# Como puedo realizar un ping a un contenedor de docker, desde la terminal

Tags: linux, windows, docker, contenedores, wsl

Quería preguntar si alguien ha podido realizar un `ping` ya sea desde `Windows PowerShell`, `wsl` o la `Terminal`, a un contenedor de `Docker`.

He intentado crear mi propia red dentro de `Docker`, que está dentro de los rangos de mi **IP**, otorgarle una **IP** manual, otorgarle un tipo de red Host, pero nada ha funcionado.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda para poder resolver este problema que llevo días intentando solucionarlo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: No creo que eso sea posible con docker.... en docker lo que haces es mapear puertos TCP/UDP del host a puertos del guest que está corriendo en docker.